# SQL Server Update Quetion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a little question about SQL Server 2008 and have a column for a game

The column is for example:

```
xx984916516518
xx191981981989
```

where

```
xx = 45 (for example)
```

Is there any way that I can update the 45 to 30 (example)

And if this is possible, can I do the same with this:

xxyy1581zz9878

```
xx = 45
yy = 45
zz = 45
```

I also want just update the 45.

I could make it with:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column = '30301581309878'
WHERE Column = '45451581459878'
```

But I have over 10.000 of this type, this would take too much time.

Comment: use Replace http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx and Substring http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Comment: this won't work with my idea, anyway thanks

Comment: As a comment Replace won't work but as and answer it looks great?

Comment: What kind of information are you storing here?  The way you need to update this suggests there's something problematic with your table design.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET SomeColumn = '30' + substring(SomeColumn, 3, LEN(SomeColumn - 2))
WHERE SomeColumn like '45%'
```

Comment: I think this might be the better approach, because it takes position of the value into account.

Answer (score 1):

**Example with Replace Function**

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'xx9849165zz16518yy'

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String, 'xx', '45'), 'zz', '45') , 'yy', '45')
```

**Result**

```
459849165451651845
```

If you want to update a column in your table you could do something like this

```
UPDATE Table_Name

SET Column_Name = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Column_Name, 'xx', '45'), 'zz', '45') , 'yy', '45')
```

**To Replace '30' with '45'**

```
UPDATE Table_Name 

SET Column_Name = REPLACE(Column_Name, '30', '45')
```